# How to write a test case for radio button and link field?

Tags: manual-testing, test-strategy

Am a beginner in manual testing. What are  the possible  scenarios for testing the radio button and link field?

Comment: What you would test depends entirely on the application and situation around those controls. What it should do? What it shouldn't do?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a lot of scenarios- both for the radio button and link field.

Let me list a few of them- I will categorize them separately

- Radio Button

In radio button test cases, you can test for the following conditions
UI cases

```
     -Is the Radio Button visible on webpage.

     - Does the radio button lists all the required options

     - Radio button should show the correct options against the radio buttons.
```

Functional - Listed above are good scenarios by @Anarch. Apart from these you can check

```
     - If the radio button allows for single or more than one selection.

     - If single selection, are you able to select more than one option (negative test case)

     - If multiple options can be done, is it happening.

     - If any event is supposed to be triggering, is it triggered.
```

Validation : Scenario 2,3  listed above are good enough to check for this.

- Link Field

  A link field should have these test cases :

  UI :

  ```
     -Is the Link field visible on webpage.

     - Input box for entering links is present.
  ```

  Functional :

  ```
     - Should recognize hyperlinks

     - Check expected vs actual behavior for different types of url (static and dynamic)

     - Is it able to validate the incorrect or broken links

     - Should only accept links (not garbage or incorrect texts)
  ```

These are something that are coming on top of the mind right now. It should be based on how much extensively you want to test both. No of test cases can be increased or decreased based on that.

Comment: 3/4 of the functional tests are incorrect. Radio buttons can only select a single option at a time.  As soon as you add multiple options, it becomes a 'checkbox'

Answer (score 0):

Scenario for a radio button.

1. Check if the radio button is triggering any event , if so check if that's happening.
2. select the button and continue with the execution , check expected result.
3. Do not select the button and continue with the execution . check the expected result.
4. If there are multiple radio buttons check whether selecting one removes the others(main purpose of having a radio button)
5. Check if the text and other minor things are in place.